# How this function passes arguments to another inner function parameters

Tags: javascript

When i check MDN to learn some points about closures, i faced the below function.

It can be a known pattern in javascript, but it's strange for java or .NET developer.
I want to know how it works, i know about arguments and first class object behavior in javascript language but how `add5(2)` assigned 2 to y variable.

```
function makeAdder(x) {
    return function(y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}

var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2));  // 7
console.log(add10(2)); // 12
```

Comment: i think i got it, cause makeAdder(x) return function(y) so the value of add5 is the function(y) so when i do add5(2) i pass 2 to y

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `makeAdder` returns a function, so the variables `add5` and `add10` are just references to functions. When you call those functions with a parameter vale, that ends up as the parameter `y` in the function.

You can do the same in C# for example, and the closure works the same:

```
public static Func<int, int> MakeAdder(int x) {
  return y => x + y;
}
```

Using it:

```
Func<int, int> add5 = MakeAdder(5);
Func<int, int> add10 = MakeAdder(10);

Console.WriteLine(add5(2));
Console.WeiteLine(add10(2));
```

Comment: I know there are also another nice answers, but this answer is awesome for me, it speak with me with the language i understand, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, any time there are named parameters - there is an implicit variable declaration.  So forget the function above, just consider this

```
var example = function() {
  var x = 5;
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}
var inner = example();
console.log(inner(5));
> '10'
```

Do you understand how the above works?  if not I'd recommend looking into javascript closure and what it means.

[Javascript Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

In the above function makeAdder, the only difference is that we are passing the value of x.  But x is still defined in the outer function, and the resulting returned function closes over its value

Answer (score 1):

`makeAdder` returns a function which can be seen like:

```
var x = 5;
function add5(y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`makeAdder(5)` called the function makeAdder, with x bound to 5. This function returns another function. Furthermore, since the value of x was provided, the anonymous function inside makeAdder knows the value of x. At this point in time, makeAdder will return:

```
function(y) {
   return 5 + y;
}
```

Therefore, by assigning this new function to add5, add5 is now a function, as well. If we call `add5(2)`, it will use the above function, and perform the following:

```
function(2) {
  return 5 + 2;
}
```

Which will output 7.

How does this work?

> The function defined in the closure 'remembers' the environment in
>   which it was created.

[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)